# turning a string with binary into binary in C#

Tags: c#, string, byte

lets say I have a string that contains binary, like this:

```
string test = "01001010";
```

so I want to do something like this:

```
someFunc(test);
```

and this function would return exactly what the test variable says, but in byte form instead of string.

example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(someFunc(Console.ReadLine())));
    }
}
```

this program prompts you to enter a byte using Console.ReadLine (which returns a string), turns it into a byte, then turns it into a char.

How could I do this?

Comment: That's not so difficult. Go from right to left trough the string. If the current digit shows 0, do nothing, if it shows 1, add 2^n (with n the digit number) to the result.

Comment: Maybe [Convert.ToByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_) helps?

Comment: What do you mean by "byte representation"?

Comment: If you mean convert `"01001010"` from binary into an integer with the value 74, you use `Convert.ToInt32(test, 2)`

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32). Converts the string representation of a number in a specified base to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This worked!!! Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Convert.ToInt32(string, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_) where `string` is the string you want to convert, and `int` is the base of the number system you want to convert from, in your case base 2 or binary. Or if you really desperately need it to be a byte, then you can use [`Convert.ToByte(string, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_). Like so:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine(); // 01001010
        var number = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(number); // prints '74'
    }
}
```

Be warned that `Convert.ToXyz()` will throw an exception of type `FormatException` if the given input string contains character that are illegal for the given base. For base 2 that would be any character that's not a `0` or `1`, you might want to catch such exceptions, or check that all characters in the input string are either a '0' or '1' beforehand

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in this way:

```
using System;

    class Program
    {
        static byte someFunc(string text)
        {
                byte t = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                         t = (byte)(t * 2 + (text[i] - '0'));
                return t;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(someFunc(Console.ReadLine())));
        }
    }
```

But it would be useful before using someFunc() to check if string is not okey (for example, that there would be shown an error message if input is "10102010")

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Take char after char, add it to result byte and multiply by 2 to convert from binary to decimal (except for the last char, it should be just added).

Then return byte as char.

```
public static char someFunc(string bs) { 
    byte result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (bs[i].Equals('1')) 
        {
            result += 1;
        }
        result *= 2;
    }
    if (bs[bs.Length - 1].Equals('1')) 
    {
        result++;
    }
    return (char) result;
}
```

returns J for "01001010"

Answer (score -1):

Hi this is one implementation which i use in java, but this will ork for c# as well. My be you need some syntax changes.

```
static int someFunc(String s){
    int binary = 0x00;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '1')
            binary =(binary<<1) | 0x01;
        else if(s.charAt(i) == '0')
            binary =(binary<<1) | 0x00;

    }
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: Or just `Convert.ToInt32(s, 2)`.